# I want to get User's Notes using SOQL with python

Tags: soql

I am doing the following query

```
querySOL = "Select Id,Body from Note"
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([('totalSize', 0), ('done', True), ('records', [])])
```

Despite having some notes in my account,Please help me correct it

Answer (score 1):

If you've enabled Enhanced Notes, you need to query the [ContentNote](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_contentnote.htm) objects instead. Try:

```
SELECT Title,Content FROM ContentNote
```